# Kendo Mobile - Where does the DataSource go in the folder structure of using the MVVM pattern?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, requirejs, kendo-mobile

I am currently working on a Kendo Mobile project using the MVVM pattern but having difficulty on how I should separate the following Kendo components:

- Schema Model
- Data Source
- ViewModel
- View

I am using RequireJS to help with modularizing my JavaScript, and would like to keep things as uncoupled as I can.  I don't really know where to put the data sources in my project. Is the following folder structure appropriate? I am using web service calls exclusively for handling my data:

> app/
>
> ```
>   model/ (all the schema models js)
>
>   dataSource/ (all the data sources with CRUD service calls js)
>
>   viewModel/ (holds all the view models js)
>
>   view/ (holds the init, beforeShow, show, afterShow functions of respective views js)
>
>   library/ (public libraries like jquery, requirejs)
>
>   common/ (utilities)
> ```

I am unsure about the folder names and such, as some articles I've read had said the model includes the data source. I don't think that's right, but I am fairly new at the MVVM pattern. Any help and recommendations of the appropriate folder structure would help a lot! As a side note, I feel that the view and viewModel folders should be combined but I am not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd like to say: "It depends." ;o)

IMHO, it depends a bit on your plans in the future. Usually, I would put the `DataSource` into the `Model` part because the `Model` is the result, which is returned by the `DataSource` but also the entities, which are passed to the `DataSource` in case of writing operations. So if you're not planning to replace your data retrievel implementation its absolutely fine to put it in there.

If you're not sure or you have already plans, I would recomment do put the `Interfaces` in the model folders, since they are still related and put the data retrieval implementation somewhere else. I think, this is usual common approach.

Hope it helps to decide.